# Equi-spacing grid columns in rainbow plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data `Kappa` values computed for different `Study`s:

```
kappa <- structure(list(Study = c("Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (no sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (no sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_1 (with sound)", 
                                  "Study_1 (with sound)", "Study_2", "Study_2", "Study_2", "Study_2", 
                                  "Study_2", "Study_2", "Study_2", "Study_2", "Study_2", "Study_2", 
                                  "Study_2", "Study_2", "Study_2", "Study_2", "Study_2", "Study_2", 
                                  "Study_2", "Study_2"), Kappa = c(0.66251262, 0.2114175, 0.72785329, 
                                                                   0.73627552, 0.4847213, 0.45167785, 0.4654613, 0.498, 0.63880643, 
                                                                   NA, 0.30765176, 0.80643405, NA, 0.2616621, 0.41163801, 0.668, 
                                                                   NA, 0.14457204, 0.36818988, 0.25263232, 0.46031023, 0.13939774, 
                                                                   0.45571076, 0.582, 0.73516352, 0.03682021, 0.64374286, 0.69094256, 
                                                                   0.39179506, 0.49107351, 0.4662689, 0.48553182, 0.65654456, NA, 
                                                                   0.14858406, 0.71859252, NA, 0.36692636, 0.36869314, 0.63041509, 
                                                                   NA, 0.27783721, 0.40108812, 0.33026679, 0.34502782, 0.16359834, 
                                                                   0.2218009, 0.62206269, 0.90625897, 0.88653293, 0.82023658, 0.79950182, 
                                                                   NA, 0.85708667, 0.89005828, 0.91490666, 0.68073868, 0.80685166, 
                                                                   0.95488826, 0.85467026, 0.81634068, NA, 0.19436544, 0.84077271, 
                                                                   0.91533355, 0.66686707)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                 -66L))
```

I want to compare the `Kappa` values by `Study`in Raincloud plots. While I'm able to produce the plots, using the below code I'm not satisfied with the outcome:

```
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("tidyquant")
library(tidyquant)
#install.packages("ggdist")
library(ggdist)
#install.packages("ggthemes")
library(ggthemes)

   
# plot:
kappa %>% 

  ggplot(
    aes(x = factor(Study), y = Kappa, fill = Study)) +
  
  geom_boxplot(
    width = 0.5,
    notch = TRUE,
    # removing outliers
    #outlier.color = NA,
    alpha = 0.5
  )+
  stat_dots(
    # ploting on left side
    side = "left",
    # adjusting position
    justification = 1.35,
    # adjust grouping (binning) of observations
    binwidth = 0.02
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Kappa across studies",
    x = "",
    y = ""
  ) +
  # remove axis labels and axis ticks
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

As can be seen from the plot, the grid is unequally spaced: the vertical grid column to the left is larger than the next two columns and the right most column is even smaller. **How can the distances be made equi-spaced?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical grid lines are equally spaced, but there is a different amount of space between the left edge and first line as compared to the last line and right edge.

The way around this is to set hard axis limits using `coord_cartesian` with `expand` set to `FALSE`

```r
ggplot(kappa, aes(x = factor(Study), y = Kappa, fill = Study)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, notch = TRUE, alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_dots(side = "left", justification = 1.35, binwidth = 0.02) +
  labs(title = "Kappa across studies", x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 4), ylim = c(0, 1), expand = FALSE) +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

To my eye this still ends up looking a little unbalanced because each raincloud is visually "left-heavy", even though the spaces between the edges and grid lines are equal.

If I were making this plot myself, I would trust my eye and shave a bit off the right edge. I would also completely get rid of the vertical grid lines, since they aren't actually helping to communicate anything, and I would remove the notches, since these exceed the hinge in the second box. Personally, I would also drop the legend in favor of directly labelling the axis. This makes the plot easier to read at a glance without having to refer back-and-forwards to the legend.

```r
ggplot(kappa, aes(x = factor(gsub('\\(', '\n\\(', Study)), 
                  y = Kappa, fill = Study)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, alpha = 0.5) +
  stat_dots(side = "left", justification = 1.35, binwidth = 0.02,
            color = 'gray40') +
  labs(title = "Kappa across studies", x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 3.8), ylim = c(0, 1), expand = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 'Dark2', guide = 'none') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]